# Determine the lifetime of a device with two components that follow exponential distributions

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables representing the lifetimes (in hours) of two key components of a device that fails when and only when both components fail. Say each $X_i$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1000$. Let $Y_1=min(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y_2=max(X_1,X_2)$, so that the space of $Y_1,Y_2$ is $0 <y_1<y_2<\infty$.
>
> Find $G(y_1,y_2)$ = $P(Y_1 \leqq y_1, Y_2 \leqq y_2)$.

Because the variables are independent we have:

$$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{10^6}e^{-(\frac{x_1+x_2}{10^3})}$$

I'm not sure how to deal with the max and min functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y_1 < y_2$

$P(Y_1 \leq y_1 , Y_2 \leq y_2) = P(\min(X_1, X_2) \leq y_1 \text{ and } \max(X_1, X_2) \leq y_2) = P( \{ X_1 \leq y_1 \text{ or } X_2 \leq y_1 \} \text{ and } X_1 \leq y_2 \text{ and } X_2 \leq y_2) = P(\{X_1 \leq y_1 \text{ and } X_2 \leq y_2 \} \text{ or } \{X_1 \leq y_2 \text{ and } X_2 \leq y_1 \})$

Now, just use the fact that $P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\text{ and } B)$.